# For deep space missions, how thick must the water filled layer within the ship's hull be to effectively shield against cosmic rays?

Tags: spacecraft, radiation, shielding

Initially i proposed a 27cm thick barrier. But im not really sure thatll be enough

Comment: Define "effectively". SNOLAB's under Earth's magnetosphere, its atmosphere, and 2 km of rock, and still gets some cosmic radiation. Roughly, each 7 cm of water doubles the amount of time it takes to reach whatever you've set as your limit for accumulated radiation dose.

Comment: Welcome to SpaceExploration. Showing some evidence of research helps on this site. You've made a start there though could you explain more about how you came up with the 27cm? e.g. what assumptions about the environment and the acceptable dose

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/space_radiation_ebook.pdf looks like a starting point. A full answer is either going to be book length or mostly consist of "it depends" though. It would help if you could narrow down the mission. I am assuming you are talking about manned missions and then the next major consideration is duration and then destination.

Answer (score 2):

Voyager 1, which is (at the moment) the deepest of all deep space missions that have ever been flown, uses no water filled layer at all, so clearly 0 cm are enough.

[It did use kitchen foil](https://businessinsider.com/voyager-kitchen-aluminum-wrap-radiation-short-circuit-2017-9), however, literally bought from a convenience store.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the physics of "attenuation lengths", that distance that reduces penetration by 1/e. This will vary with both material (attenuator), particle type, and particle energy. Lots of literature on this, especially in the health physics community. BTW, multiple layers of different materials might be more effective. For example, polyethylene is often used near fissile materials. For some types of radiation, low-Z materials (like water and plastics) are more effective than high-Z (like iron or lead). It all depends. Also remember that you will never shield against the highest energy cosmic rays. But the higher the energy, the rarer they occur. Most of manned spaceflight, however, is worried about solar radiation, which tends to be lower energy but abundant.